# How do I change the size of a bouncing ball to make it smaller for every 5 bounces and then have it return to its normal size every 5 bounces

Tags: javascript, html

How do I change the size of a bouncing ball to make it smaller for every 5 bounces and then have it return to its normal size every 5 bounces. I just started learning about HTML5 and this as far as I have gotten with my project.

```
    ball.x += xunits;
    ball.y += yunits;
    context.fillStyle = color;
    context.beginPath();
    context.arc(ball.x,ball.y,15,0,Math.PI*2,true);
    context.closePath();
    context.fill();


    if (ball.x > theCanvas.width || ball.x < 0 ) {
        angle = 180 - angle;
        color = "red";
        updateBall();
    } else if (ball.y > theCanvas.height || ball.y < 0) {
        angle = 360 - angle;
        color = "blue";
        updateBall(); 
    }

}

function updateBall() {
    radians = angle * Math.PI/ 180;
    xunits = Math.cos(radians) * speed;
    yunits = Math.sin(radians) * speed;
}

var speed = 5;
var p1 = {x:250,y:0};
var angle = 45;
var radians =0;
var xunits = 0;
var yunits = 0; 
var color = "blue";
var ball = {x:p1.x, y:p1.y};
updateBall();

theCanvas = document.getElementById('canvasOne');
context = theCanvas.getContext('2d');

function gameLoop() {
        window.setTimeout(gameLoop, 20);
        drawScreen()    
    }

gameLoop();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a counter

```
var counter = 0;
```

While  bouncing, increase counter and adust size

```
counter++;
size -= value;
```

And check for `5` where you can reset counter and size

```
if (counter === 5) {
    counter = 0;
   // size = ... reset
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yo, I think there might be too much wrong with this to help you sort through. You're using variables and functions before they are declared. `drawScreen` is not declared in the snippet you posted and is a pivotal function here.

I've cleaned it up a bit down here and I believe it is doing *most* of what you wanted. Some things I chaged are more stylistic, but the declaration order that I mentioned above is *not* stylistic and is necessary.

```
(function(window, document){
var ball = {x:250, y:30},
    color = "blue",
    speed = 20,
    angle = 45,
    radians,
    xunits,
    yunits, 

    theCanvas = document.getElementById('canvasOne'),
    context = theCanvas.getContext('2d');

function drawScreen(){
  context.beginPath();
  context.arc(ball.x,ball.y,15,20,Math.PI*2,true);
  context.fillStyle = color;
  context.fill();
  context.closePath();
function updateBall(){
    radians = angle * Math.PI/180;
    xunits = Math.cos(radians) * speed;
    yunits = Math.sin(radians) * speed;
    ball.x += xunits;
    ball.y += yunits;

    if (ball.x > theCanvas.width - 7.5 || ball.x < 7.5 ) {
        angle = 180 - angle;
        color = "red";
    } 
    if(ball.y > theCanvas.height || ball.y < 0) {
        angle = 360 - angle;
        color = "blue";
    }
}
  updateBall();
  context.clear();
}
function gameLoop() {
        window.setTimeout(gameLoop, 500);
        drawScreen();   
    }
gameLoop();
})(this, document);
```